# How many ways are $3$ letters placed consecutively. ($6$ letters from $8$ letters)

Tags: permutations, combinations

*Here are the questions:*

> $i)$How many ways can you arrange $6$ letters from the letters $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h$?
>
> $ii)$How many of those have $b,c$ and $g$ placed consecutively?

I think the solution to the first one is $8\choose 6$, I'm still not sure so please correct me if I'm wrong. I don't have an idea though how to answer the next question. Please help.
Thanks :)

Comment: What is ** 8C6**?

Comment: And can we repeat the letters? Or can only use them once?

Answer (score 0):

The number of ways to choose 6 letters from the 8 is $\binom 8 6 = \frac{8!}{6! 2!}$

each of these choices can be arranged in $6!$ ways - so the answer to i) is $\frac{8!}{ 2!}$

for ii) - 
there are $3!$ ways to arrange b,c,g consecutively 
and  $\binom 5 3 = \frac{5!}{3! 2!}$ choices of the other three letters. 
For each of these choices there will be $4!$ ways to arrange the 3 letters and the b,c,g block.

$$N=   \frac{3! 4! 5!}{3! 2!} =  \frac{4! 5!}{ 2!}$$

Comment: How can you be sure about $8\choose 6$, it also could be $8^6$. OP hasnot used the most vital  word *distinct*. Firstly study all the gaps of Question, wait for removal, and then post the final answer.

Comment: I assumed no replacement based on the OP's suggested answer and on the fact that allowing replacement would bring up a number of issues not mentioned e.g. multiple repetitions and the status of a substring like "bccg"

Comment: He could also be wrong. Actually he/she is confused about this, so he/she asked this. And he/she also did not reply the comments by @ Danijel Subotic for clarification.@WW1

Answer (score -1):

For B , C , G to occur consecutively take them as one letter only . Like X={b,c,g} you are left with 5 letters and select any 5 of them by 5C5 and the 6th would be X . You can arrange the letters inside X by 3! Ways and the six letters(which include X) by 6! Ways hence the answer should be 6! X 3!